# XSLT: Display unique rows of filtered XML recordset

Tags: xslt, muenchian-grouping

I've got a recordset that I'm filtering on a particular field (i.e. Manager ="Frannklin"). Now I'd like to group the results of that filtered recordset based on another field (Client). I can't seem to get Muenchian grouping to work right.

Any thoughts?

TIA!

CG

My filter looks like this:

`<xsl:key name="k1" match="Row" use="@Manager"/>`
`<xsl:param name="dvt_filterval">Frannklin</xsl:param>`
`<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row" />`
`<xsl:variable name="FilteredRowsAttr" select="$Rows[normalize-space(@*[name()=$FieldNameNoAtSign])=$dvt_filterval ]" />`

Templates
`<xsl:apply-templates select="$FilteredRowsAttr[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1',@Manager))]" mode="g1000a">`
`</xsl:apply-templates>`

`<xsl:template match="Row" mode="g1000a">`
  Client: `<xsl:value-of select="@Client"/>`
`</xsl:template>`

Results I'm getting
Client: Beta
Client: Beta
Client: Beta
Client: Gamma
Client: Delta

Results I want
Client: Beta
Client: Gamma
Client: Delta

Sample recordset
`<dsQueryResponse>`
`<Rows>`
`<Row   Manager="Smith" Client="Alpha " Project_x0020_Name="Annapolis" PM_x0023_="00123" />`
`<Row   Manager="Ford" Client="Alpha " Project_x0020_Name="Brown" PM_x0023_="00124" />`
`<Row   Manager="Cronkite" Client="Beta " Project_x0020_Name="Gannon" PM_x0023_="00129" />`
`<Row   Manager="Clinton, Bill" Client="Beta " Project_x0020_Name="Harvard" PM_x0023_="00130" />`
`<Row   Manager="Frannklin" Client="Beta " Project_x0020_Name="Irving" PM_x0023_="00131" />`
`<Row   Manager="Frannklin" Client="Beta " Project_x0020_Name="Jakarta" PM_x0023_="00132" />`
`<Row   Manager="Frannklin" Client="Beta " Project_x0020_Name="Vassar" PM_x0023_="00135" />`
`<Row   Manager="Jefferson" Client="Gamma " Project_x0020_Name="Stamford" PM_x0023_="00141" />`
`<Row   Manager="Cronkite" Client="Gamma " Project_x0020_Name="Tufts" PM_x0023_="00142" />`
`<Row   Manager="Frannklin" Client="Gamma " Project_x0020_Name="UCLA" PM_x0023_="00143" />`
`<Row   Manager="Jefferson" Client="Gamma " Project_x0020_Name="Villanova" PM_x0023_="00144" />`
`<Row   Manager="Carter" Client="Delta " Project_x0020_Name="Drexel" PM_x0023_="00150" />`
`<Row   Manager="Clinton" Client="Delta " Project_x0020_Name="Iona" PM_x0023_="00151" />`
`<Row   Manager="Frannklin" Client="Delta " Project_x0020_Name="Temple" PM_x0023_="00152" />`
`<Row   Manager="Ford" Client="Epsilon " Project_x0020_Name="UNC" PM_x0023_="00157" />`
`<Row   Manager="Clinton" Client="Epsilon " Project_x0020_Name="Berkley" PM_x0023_="00158" />`
`</Rows>`
`</dsQueryResponse>`

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for a complete solution. :)

Comment: Glad you liked the solution. Hint (you may select the answer -- click on the check mark) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need a compound key for this.**

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="kClientByMgr" match="@Client"
      use="concat(../@Manager, '+', .)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select=
     "*/*/*/@Client[generate-id()
          =
           generate-id(key('kClientByMgr',
                           concat('Frannklin', '+', .)
                           )[1]
                       )
           ]
     ">
      Client: <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document, produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
  Client: Beta 
  Client: Gamma 
  Client: Delta
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre!  You're a rockstar!